# linq where count of collection greater than

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class which have a collection and I want to select those object where count of its collection greater that specific value.

Here is a sample of my class

```
class Tag{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    ....
    public IList<Article> Articles { get; set; }

}
```

I have try using this linq code

```
var topTag = _tagRepo.SearchAll(ActiveState.ACTIVE)
                     .Where(t => t.Articles.Count > 50)
                     .ToList();
```

But the result is invalid, there are still many tag object with article less than 50.
what's wrong with my code? Did i do it in a wrong way?

*--- found mistake after see Agent Shark answer but already deleted ---*

I forgot to add function inside Count(x => ..) so articles of tag doesn't include past article. Now my code have work as it should be..

here is my updated code:

```
var topTag = _tagRepo.SearchAll(ActiveState.ACTIVE)
                     .Where(t => t.Articles.Count(a => a.ReleaseDate >= DateTime.Now.Date ) > 50)
                     .ToList();
```

Thanks a lot guys :D

Comment: Your code looks fine.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Are you saying that you only want items after the first 50, or are you saying that you only want to return the list if it has more than 50 items? If you only want items after the first x items, use Skip(x).

Comment: @AnthonyGatlin yes for your second guess mate.

Comment: Is it possible that your Articles lists are getting modified between when you search and when you look?

Comment: Your code snippet is insufficient to demonstrate your problem. Apparently, you have some external code (somewhere) which attempts to pull a list of tags which are linked to 50 or more articles. Your single Linq query example does not provide sufficient context.

Comment: @AnthonyGatlin sorry for my bad, but my repo just done simple task e.g 1 line code of `_session.QueryOver<Tag>().Where(a => a.IsActive == activeState.BooleanValue())`. I guess the problem wasn't coming from there and I just want to make sure if I have use count() in where clause properly.

Answer (score 0):

A small optimization for the expression:

```
var now = DateTime.Now.Date;
const int lowArticles = 50;
var topTag = _tagRepo.SearchAll(ActiveState.ACTIVE)
      .Where(t => t.Articles.Where(a => a.ReleaseDate >= now).Take(lowArticles + 1).Count() > lowArticles)
      .ToList();
```